# How to Initialize different types from a single method? (Experimental)

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

If I'm speaking a bunch of stupid things please tell me to refactor the question more because I'm not 100% sure if this is even possible and I don't know myself how to explain this correctly.

I want to Initialize different properties in my class with a single method from a inherited base class which all my `ViewModels` inherit to avoid duplicate code which could become hard to maintain as the App grows. When it comes to properties that don't have a private counter part its fine I don't need to initialize them but when it comes to the properties with private counter part its much harder as they require `gameVersion` parameter to determine which resources to load. (Game Version could be `Bronze`, `Silver`, `Gold`) this app combines previous apps together into one to allow users to play different difficulties depending on the game version.

I want to have a method `Initialize` in the base class so I can call from any view model to get the same data on the screen, such as `Level, Lifes, Score, BestScore, VideoSource, ImageSource` few to mention. Going between screens totally fine because the state is held in a dependency which stores all the game stats and game levels until I click `Start New Game` in which the classes get their states reset.

```
private void Initialize()
{
    InitializeLevelReaderResources();
    InitializeCommands();
}

private async void InitializeLevelReaderResources()
{
    ImageSource = await GameLevels.GetImageSource(CurrentGame, CurrentWord);
    VideoSource = await GameLevels.GetVideoSource(CurrentGame, CurrentWord);
}

private void InitializeCommands()
{
    NextPage = Navigation.NextPage(nameof(SpellPage)); //This could be just a new command e.g. NextPage = new Command(...);
    PreviousPage = Navigation.PreviousPage();
    UpdateStats = new Command(UpdateStatss); //UpdateStatss is just a test method for testing.
}
```

```
public int CurrentGame
{
    get => GameStats.CurrentGame;
    set
    {
        GameStats.CurrentGame = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(CurrentGame));
    }
}
public int CurrentWord
{
    get => GameStats.CurrentWord;
    set 
    {
        GameStats.CurrentWord = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(CurrentWord));
    }
}
string imageSource;
public string ImageSource
{
    get => imageSource;
    set
    {
        imageSource = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(ImageSource));
    }
}

string videoSource;
public string VideoSource
{
    get => videoSource;
    set
    {
        videoSource = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(VideoSource));
    }
}
```

What I've tried with Not only parameters but with methods too is this, but I always get `NullReferenceException` because I don't have an instance of my `ViewModel`.

```
public T InitializeLevelReaderResources<T>(object obj, string nameOfMethod, int currentGame, int currentWord, string gameVersion = "bronze")
{
    Type type = obj.GetType();
    MethodInfo methodInfo = type.GetMethod(nameOfMethod);

    var parameters = new object[] { currentGame, currentWord, gameVersion };

    return (T)methodInfo.Invoke(methodInfo, parameters);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

*"because I don't have an instance of my ViewModel"* - Right, because you are trying to initialize in a place that lacks the needed information.

Each class needs to initialize itself. Do this by putting a `virtual` method in the base class, and `override` that in each subclass:

```cs
// in base class
protected virtual async void InitializeLevelReaderResources() ...

// in each subclass
protected override async void InitializeLevelReaderResources() ...
```

When base class `Initialize` calls `InitializeLevelReaderResources()`, the version in the subclass will run.

Adapt as needed to your situation.

Comment: Could you go more in depth with the answer, I'm not sure I understand what you mean. This whole virtual method creating is very new to me as I've recently just stepped up doing much more higher level programming and I'm confused on what you mean. Sorry. Thanks

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what more to say, until you learn more about these concepts, and attempt to write code that does whatever you need. Google `c# virtual methods` and look for examples, tutorials, videos. Try to make use of these ideas, and modify the code in question. If you get stuck, then hopefully someone can help you.